# How to use scope in web worker using angular

Tags: angularjs

Here my code. But i am getting the error.Please help me on this issue.

In controller

```
if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if(typeof(worker) == "undefined") {
        var worker = new Worker("assets/scripts/directives/custommultifilter.js");
        worker.postMessage({ "getobject":scope.payloadRowCollection}); 
         worker.onmessage = function(event) {
                 console.log(event);                                         
         }
    }
 }
```

In web worker (custommultifilter.js)

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  $scope.arr = [1,2,3];
     postMessage($scope.arr);
}, false);
```

Comment: Here be my code... please help... sorry, it doesn't work like that. Explain your problem as clear and concise as possible.

Comment: I want to use $filter('filter') function in web worker (custommultifilter.js).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to share variables between web workers and the "main" script. You would run into concurrency issues if it was.

But you can communicate via events:

```
// in the worker
self.postMessage('someData);

// in angular
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
}, false);
```

Here is a good tutorial about web workers.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/